# Cant set cookie

Tags: php, cookies

i know this is going to be a multiple question, but i really dont know what to do:

I just want to set a cookie:

```
setcookie("MyCookie", 1234, time() - 3600);
```

and get the value of it on the "next" page:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

The results i get are just this:

```
Array ( [a98e53615d37a31cc52f76d8ef02a22318bae5df] => be65468d9619075da09d3bbd13e4bd2c1188378a 
        [6c046e19abae502b6c47ff83a8eb4d8727f7dd4e] => 59c90d217bc0337f5562a90a
        [dd898f14bdc9dab95346cf7057db6ffdb10ba1c8] => 593a8f217ceb6426fb9f04ae 
        [_ga] => GA1.2.721982734.1497033554 [PHPSESSID] => b5kud5gp0203en4e1d2tu687c2 )
```

I tried to use phpauth (it says to store a cookie for keeping a user logged in), but it fails at this point at the moment. There should be a cookie called 'authID' - but there is NONE.

Comment: `setcookie("MyCookie", 1234, time() - 3600);` **-3600** will destroy cookie

Comment: Set a path for the cookie. `setcookie("MyCookie", 1234, time() + 3600, "/");` and *add* the time instead of subtracting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give proper `time of expire` while you setting cookie. `time() - 3600` negative value after current time is used to remove/ destroy the cookie.
change your code to:

```
setcookie("MyCookie", 1234, time() + 3600, "/");
```

Comment: this works fine! I looked at the wrong example @ php.net :(